# Castle MonoRail with asynchronous action view render exception

Tags: exception, asynchronous, action, castle-monorail, nvelocity

I'm trying to use async actions in MonoRail but when the view is rendered I get an NullReference exception, also tested with emtpy view file.

I also tried to call RenderView("uploadTags.vm") in EndUploadTags.
When I call RenderText(s) in EndUploadTags I don't get the exception.

Stacktrace:

```
   [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Services.DefaultCacheProvider.Get(String key) +163
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Views.NVelocity.CustomResourceManager.GetResource(String resourceName, ResourceType resourceType, String encoding) +68
   NVelocity.Runtime.RuntimeInstance.GetTemplate(String name, String encoding) +57
   NVelocity.Runtime.RuntimeInstance.GetTemplate(String name) +82
   NVelocity.App.VelocityEngine.GetTemplate(String name) +47
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Views.NVelocity.NVelocityViewEngine.Process(String viewName, TextWriter output, IEngineContext context, IController controller, IControllerContext controllerContext) +564
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Services.DefaultViewEngineManager.Process(String templateName, TextWriter output, IEngineContext context, IController controller, IControllerContext controllerContext) +237
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Controller.ProcessView() +146
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Controller.EndProcess() +1579
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.BaseAsyncHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +141

[MonoRailException: Error processing MonoRail request. Action uploadtags on asyncController vendor]
   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.BaseAsyncHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +461
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +86
```

This is my test code:

```
        private Output output;
        public delegate string Output();

        private string DoNothing()
        {
            return "nothing";
        }

        private string Upload()
        {
            return "upload";
        }

        public IAsyncResult BeginUploadTags(HttpPostedFile xmlFile, Boolean doUpload)
        {
            if (IsPost)
            {
                output = Upload;
                return output.BeginInvoke(ControllerContext.Async.Callback, null);
            }
            output = DoNothing;
            return output.BeginInvoke(ControllerContext.Async.Callback, null);
        }

        public void EndUploadTags()
        {
            var s = output.EndInvoke(ControllerContext.Async.Result);
            PropertyBag["logging"] = s;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in old versions of MonoRail. It works in [MonoRail 2.1 RC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/MonoRail/2.1/), but not in an old version I just tried, I got the same null ref exception.

This is what revision 5688 looked like in Subversion, which is where the `NullReferenceException` is coming from. The [code](https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail/blob/master/MR2/src/Castle.MonoRail.Framework/Services/DefaultCacheProvider.cs) no longer uses the `HttpContext` for the cache.

```
public object Get(String key)
{
    if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
    {
        logger.DebugFormat("Getting entry with key {0}", key);
    }

    return GetCurrentContext().Cache.Get(key);
}

private static HttpContext GetCurrentContext()
{
    return HttpContext.Current;
}
```

Comment: This is not a real anwser to the question. You only ask for more details, please use comment for such demand

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I can't find how to do that. Maybe I'm limited by my low rep? Yes, I don't have 50 rep (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/missing-add-comment-link-button).

Comment: Logging is configured like this: container.AddFacility("logging", new LoggingFacility(LoggerImplementation.Log4net, "log4net.config"));

Comment: Please see my updated answer, this has nothing to do with logging but the version of MonoRail which had a defect with async actions.